# Spatie/Multitenancy multydatabase how to use ShouldBroadcast in Event?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, broadcast

I'm trying to fire an event in a controller and I get this error: Database connection [mysql] not configured. at /shared/new_tools/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:173)
here is my code:

```
//controller
event(new PushStudyPublicationEvent(auth()->user(), Tenant::current()->name));

//event

namespace App\Events\Sockets;

use App\Models\Tenant\User\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Jobs\TenantAware;

class PushStudyPublicationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast, TenantAware
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(
        public readonly User $user,
        public readonly string $tenantName
    ) {}

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'test.test';
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [new Channel($this->tenantName . '-test')];
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->user->id,
            'message' => 'hello world'

        ];
    }
}

//multitenancy.php
'queueable_to_job' => [
        SendQueuedMailable::class => 'mailable',
        SendQueuedNotifications::class => 'notification',
        CallQueuedListener::class => 'class',
        BroadcastEvent::class => 'event',
    ],

    /*
     * Jobs tenant aware even if these don't implement the TenantAware interface.
     */
    'tenant_aware_jobs' => [
        StudyDocumentCreateJob::class,
        MakeSearchable::class,
    ],
```

Works well with tasks. I tried to add the PushStudyPublicationEvent class to the "tenant_aware_jobs" array, but still got the same error.